# Winston-Rsyslog is not writing to a log file via facility 20

Tags: node.js, rsyslog, winston

I am trying to log some messages to an rsyslog server. Since I want the logs to be stored as a file I have setup a log file message.log against facility 20.

When I run this, I expect all logs to show up in message.log. But I dont see it. Any idea why?

```
    var express = require('express');

    var winston = require('winston');
        require('winston-rsyslog');

    winston.add(winston.transports.Rsyslog, {level:"silly", protocol:'T', host:"xxxxxxxx", port:514, facility: 20});


    var app = express(express.logger());


    app.get('/rsyslog', function (req, res, next) {

         winston.info('Say hello');
         winston.info('notice: %d', Date.now());
         winston.info('hostname is: ' + require('os').hostname()); 
         winston.error('error');

         res.end('all messages logged to rsyslog successfully');

    })

    app.listen(3000);
```